# Laravel 5.4 class User not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 i got and error that

> FatalThrowableError in HasRelationships.php line 487: Class 'User' not
>   found

In my model i am using the following code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use App\User;
class Review extends Model
{
 public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}
```

Could any one help me fix this error

Comment: And do you have a user class created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `App\User` in `belongsTo`. If you provide only `User` it will look for `User` in the base directory. But `User` is in the `App` namespace. :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;
use App\User;
class Review extends Model
{
 public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
}
```

**Edit :**

`belongsTo` require a namespace of a model you can achieve it either with above mentioned method or with `User::class`. As it will also return the namespace of `User` class.

```
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
```

Comment: It working fine after i added this `return $this->belongsTo(User::class);`

Comment: Yup you can use it too. I will update my answer with that.